# Offline storing Crosswalk WebView libraries?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I had my UAT today and suddenly my ionic app failed to build because it couldn't download the crosswalk webview libraries since crosswalk site was down and it is still down. After this incident I just like to keep my app build cycle completely independent of network. Can anyone help me to understand whether we can save these libraries once the the crosswalk plugin is installed and later on reference these libraries at the app build time.

This just a though and I may be completely wrong in this approach. Please help as I am migrating to the production and this issue could cause me a huge loss.

I am using ionic 1.3 and cordova 6+ crosswalk 1.6.0

Thank you in advance